# laravel 5.7 data not passed to the view

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to pass my article data to the single page article named article.blade.php although all the data are recorded into the database but when I tried to return them in my view, nothing showed and the [ ] was empty. Nothing returned.

this is my articleController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function single(Article $article)
    {
        return $article;
    }
}
```

this is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array'
    ];

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function path()
    {
        return "/articles/$this->slug";
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}
```

and this is my Route

```
Route::get('/articles/{articleSlug}' , 'ArticleController@single');
```

Comment: It should be `return view('article', ['article' => $article]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function single(Article $article)
    {
        return view('article', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

change route to

```
Route::get('/articles/{article}' , 'ArticleController@single');
```

And model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

See docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 2):

You might not be getting any data because you have not specified that you're using title_slug as the route key for model binding in your model.

Add this to your model class and it should give you the data

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Then you can return the data in json, view or other format.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you try to archive, you need to either ...

```
return $article->toJson(); // or ->toArray();
```

.. for json response or ..

```
return view(..., ['article' => $article])
```

for passing a the article to a certain view